# Github pages markdown tables are too wide, and using overflow-x: scroll does not work once code blocks are added

Tags: css, markdown, github-pages

So I've been working on a GitHub pages site for hosting my documentation.  I've been writing my own auto documentation utility that generates markdown files which are then hosted to github pages.   [This is one of the pages in question](https://sntoolbox.com/src/environment/CelestialBody.html) (This isn't an issue on desktop, only on mobile (or "thin" screens), so if you need to replicate I would recommend trying with a phone.)

I correctly modified the [assets/css/style.scss](https://github.com/crgnam-research/spacecraft-navigation-toolbox/blob/main/docs/assets/css/style.scss) file to include:

```
table {
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

This actually worked for awhile, but then I got the idea to update my utility to also include the source code for the file being documented in the actual output markdown.  Once I made this change, the source code blocks exhibit the scrolling behavior, but now the tables do not.

Has including source code blocks caused some kind of problem?  And is there a way of fixing that?